# Python - program not working all of a sudden

Tags: python, python-requests

My code stopped working without warning. I narrowed it down to `requests.get` not getting the html for the link anymore. Instead it gets `<response [200]>`.

I know for a fact it worked at one point, I don't understand what changed.

```
t = requests.get("http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/jn/変体/m0u/")
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(t.content)
lookup2 = soup2.find_all("dl", {"class":"allList"})[0]
link = lookup2.find_all("a")[0]
link = link.get("href")
link = "http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/" + link
r = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
lookup = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"meaning"})[0].text
print(lookup)
```

getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dominic/PycharmProjects/untitled2/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    lookup2 = soup2.find_all("dl", {"class":"allList"})[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `<response [200]>` is a *successful response object*, the string representation of either `r` or `t` in the code you posted.

Comment: Your code **works**, it prints `普通の形や体裁と違っていること。体裁を変えること。また、その形や体裁。` Are you certain you are not just printing `t` or `r` somewhere?

Comment: Worked fine for me printed "普通の形や体裁と違っていること。体裁を変えること。また、その形や体裁��"

Comment: I did have print(t) to get that, which I thought was the source of the error it's showing for me because it wasn't showing that earlier. The error I get is:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dominic/PycharmProjects/untitled2/main.py", line 12, in <module> lookup2 = soup2.find_all("dl", {"class":"allList"})[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: So your soup does not find anything!
Pycharm has a superb debugger. Try to set a breakpoint and go on step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes that the following line:

```
 t = requests.get("http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/jn/変体/m0u/")
```

always gives the same result. And this is most certainly not the case. The site could be down for maintenance, it could be temporarily swamped, there could be an error while rendering the site etc. etc.

These kinds of problems are communicated using HTTP status codes and can be retrieved using `t.status_code`.

If the status code is *not* 200, you can no longer make any assumptions about the HTML in `t.contents`, such as the fact that there is any `<dl>` tag present.

To make your code more robust, you can either check the status code yourself, or at the very least call `t.raise_for_status()` before using `t.contents`.

For more information, refer to the `requests` [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes).